# avoid key duplication for database insertion

Tags: database, concurrency, insert, key, unique

im not sure if the title describes my problem , 
i have table A that needs to use a unique key with each record,as following :

1.it takes the key from a table called counters(assume its 500).
2.it checks whether the last value is really used in table A (this is because someone might book the value then not complete to use it),(if used increment the value ,otherwise take it)

business wise the process is done through 2 steps: 
1.client click book id so that he/she have the key.
2.client fill the rest of the information and save , so that a new row is inserted to table A.

more than one client might be using the system concurrently , so tow of them might book same value

assume that user1 book 500 ,then user2 book 500 (user1 have not used it yet so user2 will take same key) ,then user1 inserted row into table A, then user2 inserted row into tableA

this case will cause a serious problem because both are using same key which is supposed to be unique

would you please suggest a solution for this

Answer (score 1):

In general the best option is to allocate the key when you finally insert the item into the database.

Specifically, databases provide good and reliable mechanism for this - called auto increment or serial in most databases. In the insert you simply avoid specifying the value for the serial column and it will be generated by the database engine instead. For example in mysql ([full description](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)):

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
     personId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name varchar(64) NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO Person (name) VALUES ('MyName');

SELECT last_insert_id(); -- outputs 1, 2, 3...
```

Also the ORM frameworks allow the same. JPA for example:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
Long personId;
```

In case it's not the id of the table directly, you can consider using some dummy table or sequence for generating artificial id which you then insert into the table you need.

Comment: well , the unique key im talking about is not the primery key , Table A already have the Id primary key column. well to make this clear A is a Table for some kind of business process and it needs a unique contract number

Comment: @Heba : Then it's good idea to create some dummy table which would be just used for generating the artificial key which you would then insert into the table. Or in databases which support it - you can use just sequence generator. The rule is always the same - leave it to database, it's impossible to do it on client reliably in general when it comes to clustering.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, it would be a nice solution but in my case it doesn't work for some business process complications

Answer (score 0):

Well first of I would reconsider the architecture of your solution but since that answer is so boring to get I will also try to be more constructive too.

What you want to look into is "transactions". A transaction locks a table for use by others then the one that started the transaction. This is heavily used in solutions like booking-systems where there are a limited number of seats and in online-stores where the system can run out of stock.

The theory is fairly simple but the implementation can take some some to get right. You should also be aware that you most probably will get "holes" in your series of ID´s. Meaning if user A books id 500 and user B books ID 501 and then user A cancels it´s booking without creating a record there will be no id 500.

I think my approach to your problem would be

1: User creates a record in the target table and it gets a normal primary key incremental ID.

2: Once the record is created and saved your logics request a "visual" ID from the ID´s table you describe. This is done using transactions to make sure the visual ID is uniqe.

There should be no real valid reason for you to book/create a ID before the record is actually created.

Depending on you environment transactions is implemented differently. For example in MySQL you would do something like this.

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT @A:=SUM(salary) FROM table1 WHERE type=1;
UPDATE table2 SET summary=@A WHERE type=1;
COMMIT;
```

But if you are using a ORM like Active Record or similar there should be a convenience method for it.

You could also solve this by using pure SQL scripting. I.E: create a stored procedure that creates the record and the gets a new visual ID for it. You still need to use transactions tough.